# Ubuntu installation troubles on Windows Phone

Tags: windows, phone, mtp

I tried to use [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2226702)

Whoever read my old question knows my problem.

My old question can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684115/windows-phone-problem-with-lubuntu?noredirect=1#comment995186_684115) But, I tried to use that tutorial on the top, and now when I'm connecting my phone I get

```
"No MTP devices found"
```

error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to tranfer files from one system to another including phones is to use dropbox.

32-bit:
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86" | tar xzf -

64-bit:
cd ~ && wget -O - "https://www.dropbox.com/download?plat=lnx.x86_64" | tar xzf -

Next, run the Dropbox daemon from the newly created .dropbox-dist folder.
~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd

Comment: But my internet is very slow and when i want to transfer bigger files i'il just die for waiting

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/windows-mobile-platform/articles/65385.aspx

Comment: I checked but when i'm trying to install MultiSync Package Installer shows me "Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: bonobo (>=1.0.22)" and i can't install it